# Mark constructor as __explicitly__ requiring an object type

Tags: c++, explicit, construction

I have a constructor that accepts an object of type `Material`:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass( const Material& mat ) ;
```

However, `Material` allows construction by a `Vector`:

```
Material::Material( const Vector& v ) ;
```

Therefore, `SomeClass` can allow construction by a `Vector`:

```
SomeClass m( vec ) ; // valid, since vec is constructed to a Material first,
// then is passed to the SomeClass(Material) ctor
```

However, after "shooting myself in the foot" more than once with ctors *of this type* (in different classes in the same project!) I want to *disallow* construction of `SomeClass` by `Vector` objects directly, instead always requiring a `Material` to be passed instead.

Is there a way to do this?  Somehow think it has to do with the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: ¤ You can mark the `Material::Material` constructor as `explicit`. In C++03 you had to also make sure that there was no `operator Material` in the `Vector` class. However, with C++11 you can mark also such an conversion operator as `explicit` (the best is IMHO to avoid conversion operators and instead generally provide conversion via named functions). Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without interfering with your ability to transparently construct `Material` from `Vector`.

If you make `Material`'s constructor `explicit`

```
explicit Material( const Vector& v ) ;
```

then you will *always* have to write `Material(v)` in order to construct an instance. This will prevent you from instantiating `SomeClass` with a `Vector` accidentally, but it will also break all expressions that evaluate to a `Vector` where a `Material` is expected.

This makes sense, because by not declaring the constructor `explicit` you are saying "a `Vector` is just as good as a `Material` no matter what the context". You cannot then do a half-step backward and say "oh, well, except when constructing a `SomeClass`".

Comment: YES!!  This is a great feature!

Answer (score 2):

You declare `Material(const Vector &v)` to be `explicit`; this prevents implicit conversion from one to the other.

This, of course, is not a specific restriction on `SomeClass`; it's a global ban on any instance of an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor of `Material` `explicit`:

```
explicit Material(const Vector& v) { ... }
```

Or if you don't want to do that, as a bit of a hack and with `const`-correctness as a sacrifice, remove the `const` from `const Material& mat`. You won't be able to pass a temporary object to the constructor for `SomeClass` (or a `const` instance which may be too big a sacrifice). However, that keeps you from doing `SomeClass(Material(v))` which you may want to do. So you can only get close to what you want, but I'm afraid that it's not completely possible.

Comment: Removing the `const` from the constructor param achieves the goal, but is inadvisable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, that's why I said it was a bit of a hack. I just wanted to let him know all the options, and perhaps he didn't know that temporaries can only be passed as `const` references but not just references.